# Jetpack Compose Popup's TextField cannot received keyboard input

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have the below code where I have TextField in the ComposeView as well as the Popup.

```
@Composable
fun MyCompose() {
    Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
        var popupControl by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

        Button(onClick = { popupControl = true }) {
            Text("Add Record")
        }
        if (popupControl) {
            Popup(onDismissRequest = { popupControl = false }) {
                var popupText by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
                TextField(
                    value = popupText,
                    onValueChange = { popupText = it },
                    label = { Text("Title") }
                )
            }
        }
        var mainText by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
        TextField(
            value = mainText,
            onValueChange = { mainText = it },
            label = { Text("Title") }
        )
    }
}
```

The main TextField works fine able to receive keyboard input.
However when I get the Popup open up, although I can focus on the Popup's TextField, it won't receive the Keyboard input.

Instead, all input continue to be received by the Main TextField

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I need to setup the Popup property to make it focusable

```
Popup(
    onDismissRequest = { popupControl = false },
    properties = PopupProperties(focusable = true)
) { ... }
```